# onchange method update virtual field's value

Tags: odoo

I am working on odoo v8 and I am trying to modify the access rights view in users form. I want to modify the form so that when I select a role for each module's category it will call the onchange method and update the checkboxes below (Technical Settings, Usability and Other). Currently changes made will only appear after I saved the form. But I want to make it update onfly for administrator to verify before saving into the database. But it seems when I return a dict from the onchange method the system is not aware the existence of the field (eg virtual fields like in_group_1, in_group_2 etc). Is there anyway to do this?

```
@api.v7
def check_acl(self, cr, uid, ids, my_field, context=None):
  return {'value': {'in_group_1': True}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check is administrator or not by this function

```python
 def check_user(self, uid=None):
        if uid is None:
            uid = request.uid
        is_admin = request.registry['res.users']._is_admin(request.cr, uid, [uid])
        if not is_admin:
            raise openerp.exceptions.AccessError("Only administrators can upload a module")
```

and call this function with arguments like:

```
uid = request.session.authenticate(request.db, login, password) 
self.check_user(uid)
```

and you can use this function in your onchange

```
@api.v7
def check_acl(self, cr, uid, ids, my_field, context=None):
   if self.check_user(uid):
       return {'value': {'in_group_1': True}}
```